# Include Spring Security as dependency without auto configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I want to create a library (let’s call it **common-library**) where I need to include classes from Spring Security.

How to include Spring Security as a dependency without triggering auto-configuration?

Idea is that Spring Security will be configured by different library (called **secure-library** - also includes Spring Security).

If only the **common-library** is included in an application then Spring security must not be enabled, but if both, **common-library** and **secure-library**, libraries are included that Spring Security is enabled and configured by **secure-library**.

Classes I actually need to include:

```
org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Request;
```

BTW: I could not find jar with `OAuth2Authentication`, 
`OAuth2Request` and without auto configuration.

Comment: So if the auto-config is triggered, I assume this is sping-boot enabled application and you're not trying to create spring-agnostic common-security library? Why not disable specific spring-boot auto-config classes, like so @SpringBootApplication(exclude = org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)? Is this not working for your case?

Comment: I had mixed results with it. What is right place to disable auto configuration class(es)? Application itself, or the common-libray?

Comment: What do you mean by "mixed results"? This is the standard way for disabling auto configuration as far as I know.

Comment: The application itself should be responsible, during the bootstrap phase, for instantiating and configuring components. The application itself is the place to do it. SpringBoot behaves in a similar way - for example if it detects particular jar on the classpath, it assume you want to run the jar, so it executes some auto-configuration by default. This behavior can be disabled as shown in my previous comment.

Comment: @hovanessyan What I would like to achieve is to be able to include common-library into an application without worry about disabling Spring Security in the application. Is this right approach, or should I just state "if you include common-library, Spring Security comes with it" and eventually disable it if you wish?

Comment: @MichalFoksa it sounds to me like you should just separate the security module from the commons